# Why is uniq needed in this problem? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

New to coding, and trying to study independently. Working on a problem on Ruby, where we create a method (filter_out!) that mutates the original array to remove true elements when the array is passed through a proc. The only stipulation is that we aren't allowed to use Array#reject!.

Can anyone explain to me why

`arr.uniq.each { |ele| arr.delete(ele) if prc.call(ele)}`

works and

`arr.each { |ele| arr.delete(ele) if prc.call(ele)}`

does not? Here are two example problems:

```
arr_2 = [1, 7, 3, 5 ]

filter_out!(arr_2) { |x| x.odd? }

p arr_2     # []

arr_3 = [10, 6, 3, 2, 5 ]

filter_out!(arr_3) { |x| x.even? }

p arr_3     # [3, 5]
```

I've looked it up and understand #uniq removes duplicate values, right?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated-thank you!

edit: Looked into it more, is it because uniq will use the return value of the proc for comparison? Still not sure why this is needed for some numbers, but not all.

Comment: Hello, your question is not really clear. Can you provide examples when it does not work as you'd expect (what is the result with and without `uniq` and what are you expecting?)

Comment: @Zenibo [`delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) method can do what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Zenibo according to my understanding the first version where is using [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) method creates copy of array then looping over the copy to delete elements from the original array but in the second version same array is being directly modifying which is being used for looping, modifying the same array while looping over it might product unexpected results

Comment: @Chandan thanks, I think that explains it in a nutshell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only stipulation is that we aren't allowed to use Array#reject!.

This is an incredibly braindead stipulation. You could just use [`Array#select!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select-21) and invert the condition, or use [`Array#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject) together with [`Array#replace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-replace), for example.

> Can anyone explain to me why
>
> `arr.uniq.each { |ele| arr.delete(ele) if prc.call(ele)}`
>
> works and
>
> `arr.each { |ele| arr.delete(ele) if prc.call(ele)}`

Whenever you don't quite understand what a piece of code does, a good idea is to just run it yourself with a pen and a piece of paper.

So, let's just do that. Assume `arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 2]` and `prc = -> e { e.even? }`.

[`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) iterates through the array, we don't exactly know *how* it does it (that is the whole idea of abstraction), but we can imagine that it keeps some kind of index to remember which part of the array it is currently at.

So, during the first iteration of the array, the index is at the first element, and the array looks like this:

```ruby
 [1, 2, 4, 5, 2]
# ↑
```

`Array#each` passes `1` to the block, which in turn passes it to `prc`, which returns `false`, thus the block doesn't do anything.

`Array#each` increases the index, so now our array looks like this:

```ruby
 [1, 2, 4, 5, 2]
#    ↑
```

`Array#each` passes `2` to the block, which in turn passes it to `prc`, which returns `true`. As a result, the block now passes `2` to [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete), which deletes every element from the array that is equal to `2`. So, now the array looks like this:

```ruby
 [1, 4, 5]
#    ↑
```

`Array#each` increases the index, so now our array looks like this:

```ruby
 [1, 4, 5]
#       ↑
```

`Array#each` passes `5` to the block, which in turn passes it to `prc`, which returns `false`, thus the block doesn't do anything.

`Array#each` increases the index, so now our array looks like this:

```ruby
 [1, 4, 5]
#          ↑
```

Since index is past the end of the array, the iteration is done, and the result is `[1, 4, 5]`.

As you can see, the problem is that you are *mutating* the array *while* iterating over it.

> I've looked it up and understand #uniq removes duplicate values, right?

Correct, but that has nothing to do with why it makes your code work. Or, more precisely, makes it *seem* to work because there are actually a lot of other problems with your code as well.

It is not the fact that [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) removes duplicate values that is relevant, it is the fact that `Array#uniq` returns a *new* array. Since `Array#uniq` returns a new array, you are *no longer* mutating an array while iterating over it, you are mutating one array while iterating over another.

You could have used *any* method of [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) or one of its ancestors that returns a new array, for example [`Object#clone`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-clone), [`Object#dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-dup), [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map), or [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select), or even something really creative such as [`arr + []`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```ruby
arr.select { true }.each {|ele| arr.delete(ele) if prc.call(ele) }
```

In fact, you don't even need to return an `Array`, you only need to return some kind of [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html), such as an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html), for example using [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each):

```ruby
arr.each.each {|ele| arr.delete(ele) if prc.call(ele) }
```

> edit: Looked into it more, is it because uniq will use the return value of the proc for comparison? Still not sure why this is needed for some numbers, but not all.

Since you are not passing the proc to `Array#uniq`, it *cannot possibly* use it for anything, so it is clearly impossible for this to be the explanation.

Note that, as I explained above, there are more problems with your code than just mutating an array while iterating over it.

Even if your original code *did* work, it would actually still be broken. You are using `Array#delete` to delete the element for which `prc` returns `true`. The problem is that `Array#delete` deletes *all* elements in the array that are `#==` to the element you are passing as an argument, even the ones for which the `prc` might return `false`.

Here is a trivial example:

```ruby
a = [2, 2, 2]

i = -1

filter_out!(a) { (i += 1) == 1 }
```

This should only filter out the second element, but actually deletes all of them, so the result is `[]` when it actually should be `[2, 2]`.

Your version with `Array#uniq` makes this problem even worse, because after running `Array#uniq`, the array doesn't even *have* a second element any more! So, the result is `[2]`, when it actually should be `[2, 2]`.

The next problem is the name of the method: `filter_out!`. Bang methods (i.e. methods whose name ends with an exclamation mark `!`) are used to mark the *more surprising* method of a *pair* of methods. You should *never* have a bang method on its own. The name `filter_out!` should *only* be used if and only if there is also a `filter_out` method. So, the method should be named `filter_out`.

And the last problem is that you are mutating the argument that is passed into the method. That is an absolute no-no. You *never, ever* mutate an argument that is passed into a method. Never. You never break somebody else's toys, you never touch somebody else's privates.

Mutation, *in general*, should be avoided as much as possible, since it can lead to confusing and hard to track down bugs, as you so beautifully have discovered yourself. Only if *absolutely necessary* should you mutate state, and *only* state that you yourself own. Never mutate somebody else's state. Instead, `filter_out` should return a *new* array with the results.

Here are a couple of examples what `filter_out` could look like:

```ruby
def filter_out(enum)
  enum.select {|el| !yield el }
end

def filter_out(enum)
  enum.reduce([]) {|acc, el| if yield el then acc else acc + [el] end }
end

def filter_out(enum)
  enum.each_with_object([]) {|el, acc| acc << el unless yield el }
end
```

Note: Personally, I am not a big fan of [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), because it relies on mutation, so I would avoid that solution as much as possible.

However, the *real* problem seems to be that whatever course or book or tutorial or class you are following seems to be pretty terrible, both a teaching Ruby, and at teaching good Software Engineering practices, such as testing and debugging.

Comment: Both mutating the array and deleting all instances were intentional, though less than ideal coding etiquette (per the problem-I tried to summarize it). I did try debugging it and I didn't realize that #each indexes as it goes and uses that to keep track of its location in an array/etc. -that's why I asked the question, so thank you for your response. Currently, I'm using app academy because I can only afford free coding lessons and books, and considering I'm about a month from starting from nothing, I'd say I'm improving. I'd love to hear your suggestions though if you have better resources.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you have witnessed has nothing to do with the fact that a proc is present. The problem is that you are invoking a method (`Array#each`) on a receiver (the array) that is altered (*mutated*) in the method's block.

Suppose:

```
arr = [true, false, true]
```

```
arr.each do |x| puts "x = #{x}, arr = #{arr}"
                arr.delete(x)
                puts "arr = #{arr}"
end 
  #=> [false]
```

The following is printed:

```
x = true, arr = [true, false, true]
arr = [false]
```

You were perhaps expecting to see an empty array returned, not `[false]`.

As you see from the printed output, only `arr[0] #=> true` was passed to `each`'s block. That caused `arr.delete(x)` to delete both instances of `true` from `arr`, causing `arr` to then equal `[false]`. Ruby then attempts to pass `arr[1]` to the block but finds that `arr` has only one element so she concludes she is finished and returns `arr #=> [false]`.

Had `arr = [true, true, true]` the return value (an empty array) would be correct, but only because all elements are removed when the first element of `arr` is passed to the block. This is analogous to the example in the question of removing all odd elements of `[1, 7, 3, 5]`.

Even when the code is technically correct it is considered bad practice to invoke a method on a receiver that alters the receiver in its block.

If we first invoke `uniq` we are no longer iterating over the array we are modifying, so all is well:

```
a = arr.uniq
  #=> [true, false]
a.each do |x| puts "x = #{x}, arr = #{arr}"
              arr.delete(x)
              puts "arr = #{arr}"
end
  #=> [true, false]
```

The following is printed:

```
x = true, arr = [true, false, true]
arr = [false]
x = false, arr = [false]
arr = []
```

Similarly,

```
a = arr.dup
  #=> [true, false]
a.each do |x| puts "x = #{x}, arr = #{arr}"
              arr.delete(x)
              puts "arr = #{arr}"
end
  #=> [true, false, true]
```

The following is printed:

```
x = true, arr = [true, false, true]
arr = [false]
x = false, arr = [false]
arr = []
x = true, arr = []
arr = []
```